# Why is my Pandas dataframe converting values to NaT?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, timedelta

I have a dataframe with a 'datetime' column of type datetime64[ns], and I'm trying to add a column with the difference between the current time and then next time in a numpy array of datetimes.

```
time_since_cpi = pd.DataFrame(df['datetime'].to_numpy()[:, None] - CPI_DATETIMES_UTC_LIST)
time_since_cpi[time_since_cpi<np.timedelta64(0,'ns')] = pd.NaT
time_since_cpi.min(axis=1,skipna=True)
```

gives:

```
0                    NaT
1                    NaT
2                    NaT
3                    NaT
4                    NaT
               ...      
289018   9 days 19:19:00
289019   9 days 19:20:00
289020   9 days 19:21:00
289021   9 days 19:22:00
289022   9 days 19:23:00
Length: 289023, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Which is expected, but when I try to add this to the dataframe:

```
df['time_since_cpi'] = time_since_cpi.min(axis=1,skipna=True)
df['time_since_cpi']
```

All values are NaT?

```
1346869   NaT
1346870   NaT
1346871   NaT
1346872   NaT
1346873   NaT
           ..
1635887   NaT
1635888   NaT
1635889   NaT
1635890   NaT
1635891   NaT
Name: time_since_cpi, Length: 289023, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

This is driving me crazy.

Comment: your column datatype is `timedelta64`, if you try to put any other datatype's value there, it'd result in `NaT` values.

Comment: it looks like the indices might not be aligned, i.e. that of your dataframe and that of the series you try to include in the df